# Inner join returns more records than original tables

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to count the data records from Hive table t1 that have profile_emails that appear in Hive table t2. Multiple records can have the same profile_email in t1, but t2.profile_email is unique. I would expect a result count of < 11,681,830 (since some t1.profile_emails are not in t2). Instead it massively blows up. How is this possible with an inner join?? (and how do I fix it?)

```
select count(*) from t1;
#11,681,830

select count(*) from t2;
#1,661,773

SELECT count (*) FROM t1
inner JOIN t2 ON t1.profile_email = t2.profile_email
#1,519,465,221
```

Comment: You may have a lot of e-mails not filled at all, in both tables.

Comment: Basic SQL. `profile_email` is non-unique in both tables. e.g. myemail@whatever appears 3 times in t1 and 4 times in t2 which results in 12 records after the JOIN. P.s. Do you use a default email by any chance?

Comment: You need to find the right `join` key between the table.  Clearly, the email is not providing the 1-1 or 1-n relationship that you are expecting.

Comment: As I said in my question: email fields are unique in t2 so it shouldn't be possible to have more emails than the amount in t1. There aren't any null values in t2 either.

Comment: please refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141463/inner-join-with-count-on-three-tables

Comment: @KeyurBhanderi - How is that post related?

Comment: Ok, my mistake, it seems that there are duplicates and nulls in t2 afterall. Sorry folks! For others reading this issue, this is the query I used to check it: select profile_email, count(*) as n 
from t2
group by profile_email
order by n desc ... should have tried that before posting -_-