# Mysql query gives me same count from both tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm getting users and counting their likes and their items on other tables. The problem is every time likes_count equals created_count. If I removed the second join of the items. It just works fine and get's the right count for the likes. Any help please. I'm using laravel.

```
$users = User::select(DB::raw('users.id, users.name, 
                users.email,users.image,
                COUNT(likes.id) AS likes_count,
                COUNT(items.id) AS created_count'))
            ->leftJoin('likes', 'users.id', '=', 'likes.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('items', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: it's because when you have two joins, ultimately count() function return the number of final row which is both equal in this case.

Comment: you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141463/inner-join-with-count-on-three-tables as reference.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA I checked the reference and tried to add groupBy but not working for me.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA Thanks. I found a solution in the link you sent me. Thanks

Comment: Mention not we are here to help each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Laravel, They discourage to write raw database queries. So Always try to stick with laravel.

```php
$users = User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'image'])
             ->withCount('likes')
             ->withCount('items')
             ->get();
```

It's that simple.

**NOTE**

Note that you need to have defined those models and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue. By adding distinct inside count. Thanks to @ CHARITRASHRESTHA. I found that answer in the link he provided.

```
$users = User::select(DB::raw('users.id, users.name, 
                users.email,users.image,
                COUNT(distinct likes.id) AS likes_count,
                COUNT(distinct items.id) AS created_count'))
            ->leftJoin('likes', 'users.id', '=', 'likes.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('items', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code into user model.

```
public function likes(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Likes','user_id','id');
}
public function items(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Items','user_id','id');
}
```

and use below query to get count:

```
$users =  User::select(['id', 'name', 'email', 'image'])->withCount('likes','items')->get();
```